# Android widget RemoteViewsFactory Member data not persistent?

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

I have an Android app widget showing a gridview of tiles. Each tile contains stock quote information. I query stock quotes information from a webserver and store it in a ArrayList (stock_info_list)- a member variable of RemoteViewsFactory.

The problem is after sometime of inactivity, when I try to scroll the gridview, it goes empty - empty view comes up - meaning the ArrayList is cleared. Why is the ArrayList in RemoteViewFactory clears out automatically? If I press refresh button, which causes onDataChanged() to be called, to repopulate the ArrayList, the widget is filled with stock quotes again.

How can I make so that the data stays persistent so when you scroll the widget the data does not disappear?

```
package com.screenulator.stocktile;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService;
import android.widget.TextView;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MyWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return new MyRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), arg0);
    }

}

class MyRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory 
{
    final public DecimalFormat DF2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    public ArrayList<StockInfo> stock_info_list = new ArrayList<StockInfo>();
    private Context mContext;
    private int mAppWidgetId;

    public MyRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        mContext = context;
        mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    public void onCreate() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return stock_info_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) 
    {
        Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.my_grid_layout);
//      rv.setTextViewText(R.id.symbol, "Hello");

        StockInfo symbol_info = stock_info_list.get(position);
        if (symbol_info != null) 
        {
                       // details of initialize each grid omitted
        }


        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("remoteviews_factory", "onDataSetChanged");   
        DataServerInstance d = DataServerInstance.getInstance();
        if (d.stock_info_list.size() > 0)
        {
            stock_info_list.clear();
            stock_info_list = d.duplicate_stock_info_list();
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the remote view directly control the listview.  Have the main view update the listview from data it gets from the remote one.

Comment: What do you mean by main view? activity view inside the app? What if user does not run the app. Please give an example.

Comment: I am saying to keep ArrayList used for the listview separate from what you get from the remote view.  When you get data from the remote view, you can decide to use it or not.

Comment: How do you pass data from remote view to remoteviewsfactory? I have added my code to be clear. "stock_info_list" is the ArrayList in question. It gets initialized onDataChanged() directly from a singleton data server.